# jQuery Tag input only allow valid email address

Tags: jquery, email, tags

There are lots of jQuery Tag plugins for inputs, like jQuery Tag it, TagBox, etc... .

But in my case, I'm gonna get a list of email addresses from the user, so it doesn't need any auto complete etc, but it needs to accept the entries which are valid emails, and separated by comma, so if I type "blabla," the "blabla" is not a valid email address, so it should not considered as a tag. obviously "spaces" are not allowed since there are no spaces in email addresses.

Any easy suggestions for this?

Regards,

Comment: Search for a regular expression that validates e-mail, there are lots of variations depending on what exactly you wish to allow in those e-mails etc.

Comment: use the jquery.validate plugin

Comment: @adeneo It's needs time to add some regex filters to existing tag plugins since some of them are complicated with lots of capabilities... I asked for some easy solutions, thanks

Comment: @Kir Have you read the question!?

Comment: @behz4d - You're not going to find anything easier than applying a simple regex to the input value, other than just doing : `<input type="email" />`, but that does'nt really work in older browsers as it's HTML5.

Comment: You could split the string up, then do some smaller checks like `.contains("@")` and the like. But really, just listen to adeneo here, Regular Expressions were built specifically for this type of problem.